# Is there a more clear and concise way to express this statement with better LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections of elements. I am trying to take all elements in the first collection which have a matching ID in the second collection and run the CopyToDomain method against the matching elements.

The following code works fine, but I was a bit surprised by its verbosity. ReSharper isn't recommending anything here, but I was wondering if doing an intersection of the two collections and then mapping the method over the elements would be more clear? Would you make that change, or should I stop fussing and leave this as it is?

```
Task task = new Task();
IList<TaskAttributeDto> taskAttributeDtos = new List<TaskAttributeDto>();
taskAttributeDtos.Add(new TaskAttributeDto{ ID = 1});
taskAttributeDtos.Add(new TaskAttributeDto{ ID = 2});

foreach (TaskAttributeDto taskAttributeDto in taskAttributeDtos)
{
    TaskAttribute matching = task.TaskAttributes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == taskAttributeDto.ID);
    if (matching != null)
    {
        taskAttributeDto.CopyToDomain(matching);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have a typo, where is `task` defined?

Comment: Sorry, this is just a snippet of code. I can provide the whole thing if its relevant, but it's just an object being passed into a method.

Comment: "Clear and concise" are awfully ambiguous and subjective. I think your original code is clear and simple, while these LINQ answers are hard to read. But that's just my opinion; there's no real right answer.

Comment: That's about what I'm asking. I understand that there's no real right answer, but sometimes a 'surprisingly simple' LINQ query comes up. I'm not advocating writing code as cleverly as possible. I just like to check when I think something might have an easy simplification that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're doing is basically a join, so you can use the Linq join syntax:

```
var matches =
    from dto in taskAttributesDtos
    join attribute in task.TaskAttributes on dto.ID equals attribute.ID
    select new { dto, attribute};

foreach (var m in matches)
    m.dto.CopyToDomain(m.attribute);
```

Comment: Would you prefer to see this code in the wild over my original code? I'll be the first one to admit that I am unfamiliar with LINQ's expression queries.

Comment: This code separates levels of abstraction nicely (and is the reason I think linq is so important), whereas the original code is mixing levels of abstraction by selecting the items to process in multiple places.  Even this code can be made a little better by extracting the first linq statement into a well named function.

Comment: @SeanAnderson, I think I would prefer mine, but I guess it's a matter of personal preference and habit... I think the Linq query syntax is more expressive in this case, but don't force it on yourself if you're not comfortable with it. The best code is often the one you can easily understand.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Keep in mind that this code is also quite a bit more efficient for larger data sets.  You perform a join by iterating over the other set for each item in the first, whereas LINQ stores one in a hash-based data structure to avoid doing a linear search.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(TaskAttributeDto taskAttributeDto in taskAttributeDtos.Where(t1 => TaskAttributes .Any(t2 => t2.Id == t1.Id)))
{
    taskAttributeDto.CopyToDomain(taskAttributeDto);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about the readability of query syntax, you can try using method syntax:

```
var matches = taskAttributesDtos.Join(task.TaskAttributes,
                                      a => a.ID,
                                      b => b.ID,
                                      (a, b) => new { dto = a, attribute = b } );

foreach (var m in matches)
    m.dto.CopyToDomain(m.attribute);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
task.TaskAttributes.Where(t => taskAttributeDtos.Select(d => d.ID).Contains(t.ID))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(t => taskAttributeDtos.First(d => d.ID == t.ID).CopyToDomain(t));
```

Comment: This approach is inefficient, you're searching the DTO twice

Answer (score 0):

The original code finds the first match.  A join finds all matches, and a group join allows you to pick a winner from each matching group.

```
var matches =
    from dto in taskAttributesDtos
    join attribute in task.TaskAttributes
      on dto.ID equals attribute.ID
      into attributeGroup  //into clause causes GroupJoin to be called.
    select new { dto, attribute = attributeGroup.First() };

foreach (var m in matches)
    m.dto.CopyToDomain(m.attribute);
```